# How to call an onclick function from a radio button when it is changed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I'm working a CGI file and it gets the below parameter from query string and uses it as shown below.

```
$rettype = p->param('rettype');
if($rettype eq "A")
{
$achecked="checked";
$rchecked="";
}
if($rettype eq "R")
{
$achecked="";
$rchecked="checked";
}
```

This is used in later portion of the file that chooses which radio button needs to be selected.

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="gctyp" VALUE="a" $achecked onClick="showTextArea()";>Add
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="gctyp" VALUE="r" $rchecked onClick="hideTextArea()";>Remove
```

Now, I want the onclick JS function present in the radio button to be called based on which option was checked. It happens dynamically and the function isn't getting called.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like Perl, isn't it?

Comment: @VisioN It is perl-cgi

Comment: I'm confused. This is tagged Perl, but it's about sending a DOM event in the browser, none of which support Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are executing some Perl code and printing direct HTML to the output. That's known as hardcoded HTML and is not a good practice. Look into templating modules like [Template::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template%3a%3aToolkit) for better results and cleaner code. Also, for your own good, I hope you are using `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your Perl code.

Also, your HTML tags are written in uppercase. That's deprecated, use lowercase tags and parameters, and add `/` before closing tags that don't have a closing tag, just like `input` case.

That being said, this is an example of how to solve what you mentioned:

```
my $javascript_call;

$rettype = p->param('rettype');
if ($rettype eq "A") {
    $achecked = "checked";
    $rchecked = "";
    $javascript_call = 'showTextArea()';
}
if ($rettype eq "R") {
    $achecked = "";
    $rchecked = "checked";
    $javascript_call = 'hideTextArea()';
}

print <<END;
    <input type="radio" name="gctyp" value="a" $achecked onclick="showTextArea()" />Add
    <input type="radio" name="gctyp" value="r" $rchecked onclick="hideTextArea()" />Remove
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $javascript_call
    </script>
END
```

I'm just adding an extra variable containing a call that will be executed after printing the radio buttons and using the same code structure you presented for that.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip and the solution. :)